# Jackson JSON deserialization without custom deserializer

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have this JSON:

```
{"result":{"code":"OK",
           "message":"",
           "user":{"id":"1",
                   "name":"YingYang",
                   "mail":"somemail@gmail.com"
                  }
           }
}
```

ApiResult class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ApiResult {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String code;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;

    @JsonProperty(value = "user", required = false)
    public User user;
}
```

And User class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DefaultContract.User.TABLE)
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = DefaultContract.User._ID)
    public int id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DefaultContract.User.NAME)
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("mail")
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DefaultContract.User.EMAIL)
    public String mail;
}
```

What I need is an ApiResult object with three properties: code (String), message (String) and user (User).

I don't want User to be an inner class in ApiResponse i.e. I don't want

```
class ApiResult(){
 ...
 class User(){...}
 ...
}
```

Is there a proper way to change this in order to use ObjectMapper() without a custom deserializer?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What `to be an inner class in ApiResponse` means ?

Comment: Can you please share your expected JSON output?

Comment: So if I am not wrong, you don't want User class, you want that data in String format.

Comment: Can you please share exactly what you want in JSON format in the question?

Comment: I edited my question to solve all your doubts

Comment: So you want a separate User class

Comment: I think this should work with separate class also. is their any exception you are getting ?

Comment: public class ApiResult<T> {... public T data; ...}

Comment: sorry @Yrgl but I don't get you... could you be more explicit?

Comment: @Jared, i mean use generics and you can declare any type of receiving data, i.e. new ApiResult<User>()